# Padding, when no text inside the element show a dot size structure

Tags: css

Data is coming dynamically to the element having the following Css properties.

```
display:inline-block;
background-color: #E0CAC0;
padding: 4px;
```

Whenever data is not empty. Its look pretty. But when there is no data or text inside the element. It show a dot with size 8px*8px with background color, as it has padding property. I want no dot whenever there is no text.
I can do that with JavaScript. I want to know can I do that with a css property.

*Remember, when there is text inside the element there must be padding of 4px from each side.*

Comment: Can you please create a demo of your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the CSS pseudo-class ":empty" -- You can define two different styles based on whether or not the element has content.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aempty

This would give you something like this:

```
.class {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #E0CAC0;
    padding: 4px;
}
.class:empty {
    display:none;
}
```